# ASP.NET 4 Forms Authentication problem with UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, asp.net-4.0, browsercaps

I read of a similar issue at [Asp.Net Forms Authentication when using iPhone UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158550/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-when-using-iphone-uiwebview) where using a UIWebView is not recognized by asp.net 4 browser capabilities.  My web site is not functioning from an iPhone/iPad such as the login at https://www.nc-software.com/login.aspx due to this.

Can someone please provide the exact info I need to create in an App_Browsers folder please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using for my custom browser definition named "generic2.browser" placed in App_Browsers to get my UIWebView to work with asp.net 4 forms authentication.

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Mozilla" >
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```