# FormsAuthentication: UserData lost (but in Cookie)

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication, mobile-safari, user-data

- Asp.Net MVC 3
- FormsAuthentication (custom)
- iPad MobileSafari
- iframe (same domain)

After struggling with `formsTicket.UserData` not working with **MobileSafari** (ONLY MoblieSafari), I found out, that `httpContext.User.Identity.Ticket.UserData` is **empty** (in MobileSafari, not the others) and the original FormsAuthentication **HttpCookie** contains the **right values**?!?

How can that be?!

Code:

```cs
public void UpdateContext()
{
    if (httpContext.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
    {
        // Get Forms Identity From Current User
        FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity;
        // Create a custom Principal Instance and assign to Current User (with caching)
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        var cookieUserData = ticket.UserData; // not empty
        var httpContextIdentiyUserData = id.Ticket.UserData; // empty!
        ...
    }
}
```

Any clue would be helpful!

Lg
Warappa

PS: If it matters, I use a page of my website in an iframe - same domain.

Comment: find this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158550/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-when-using-iphone-uiwebview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was the following:
This error arose **when I logged** out and accessed a page that did a **`history.back()`**.

Looking at the traffic with Fiddler I saw, that Asp.Net used the ***cookieless***  **authentication mode**, so the authentication was ***encoded into the url***. Now, when the `history.back()` occurred, the url pointed to the **Logout url with** the now **invalid authentication information**... nasty bug at my side.

**Forcing Asp.Net to use cookies did the trick!**

Lg
warappa

Comment: This is old question but i faced with similar issue. Can you please explain how to you force asp.net to use cookies? Thank you in advance, and sorry for interupting you :))