# Add additional information into ASP.net auth cookie?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to add additional information into the ASP.NET authentication cookie?  I would like to save my own internal user key in the cookie, and have it expire at the same time as the auth cookie per this question:
[MVC save a token in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170618/mvc-save-a-token-in-session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
        public class CookieDto
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public string AuthenticationKey { get; set; }
            public bool Persist { get; set; }
            public string RememberMeToken { get; set; }
        }
```

Persist method,

```
public void Persist(CookieDto cookieDto, bool persistent)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer();
    var serializedCookie = serializer.Serialize(cookieDto);
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, cookieDto.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(90),
        persistent, serializedCookie);
    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90) };
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Get method,

```
 public CookieDto GetCookie()
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
            {
                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer();

                return serializer.Deserialize<CookieDto>(ticket.UserData);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

remove method,

```
public void RemoveCookie()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Good Luck!