# Handling cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a PhoneGap app with server session usage. It needs cookies to handle the session. Additionally, the cookie from the load balancer should be handled, too. So there is no way around. How do you handle Cookies in your PhoneGap app?

I have already accomplished some research:

- Some say cookie handling might depend on the server not setting cookies for unknown user agents (IIS): [PhoneGap session (cookies) on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019418/phonegap-session-cookies-on-ios)
- In JavaScript cookies can be set with document.cookie = ..., but they are not saved in PhoneGap and lost. Before firing xhr requests it works.
- Cookies can be retrieved after xhr request with xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'). But only when actually set on the server. Unfortunately, jQuery strips the "Cookie" header.
- The JavaScript document.cookie property is not assigned and not updated after (xhr)requests.
- Some suggest the localStorage to save session ids etc. But all scripts can access it and this might be XSS security issue. Cookies work around this issue by using the httponly flag.
- iOS: There are some modifications which will change the webView behaviour to support cookies. But they seem not to work with iOS 6 and PhoneGap 2.5: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/ZJE1nxX63ow
- Cookies seem to be enabled by default in the AppDelegate.m (v2.5).

Comment: What you mean all scripts can access localStorage? I thought it was separate and kinda sandboxed for each PhoneGap app... no?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184567/is-local-storage-for-a-phonegap-app-on-an-android-device-separate-from-the-built

Comment: Maybe this plugin helps? https://github.com/assembly/cordova-cookie-jar

Answer (score 69):

Friend, I've tried too without success to use cookies with phonegap. The solution was use localStorage.

Key Quick Example:

```
 var keyName = window.localStorage.key(0);
```

Set Item Quick Example:

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Get Item Quick Example

```
 var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
 // value is now equal to "value"
```

Remove Item Quick Example:

```
 window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Clear Quick Example:

```
 window.localStorage.clear();
```

If you use you javascript for both mobile and web, you can use this code to detect that enviroment:

```
var wl = window.location.href;
var mob = (wl.indexOf("android")>0);
```

References:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/storage/storage.html#page-toc-source

Be aware: using anonymous navigation on iOS may make localstorage not work like spected. A simple test that are working fine to me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('test', '1');
    } catch (Err) {
        if (Err.message.indexOf('QuotaExceededError') > -1) {
            // Tell the user they are in anonymous mode
            // Sugest it to go to https://support.apple.com/pt-br/HT203036 to get help to disable it
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tiago, Regarding your answer, could you please clarify if localStorage option persists (no data lose happens)  till the app is uninstalled ?    and also , can we say that it is for sure that other apps cannot reach a key-value pair that I set in my app ?

Comment: @shamaleyte "LocalStorage acts more like cache rather than cookies, where the persistence of each is dependent on user's browser settings, and how the browser itself implements it (since there are no specs for it)"   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948284/how-persistent-is-localstorage

Comment: Please DO NOT use localstorage in Cordova! in iOS the system process can flush localstorage at will. https://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/

Answer (score 6):

Similar to you I wanted to use cookies set by a server within my application so that my app would be consistent with the web and not require a separate device-ID or other method for authentication.

What I discovered is the following:

- Cookies set via AJAX (e.g. jQuery `$.get()` or `$.post()`) do not persist
- Cookies set in an 'inAppBrowser' **do** persist.

The way to thus get a cookie to persist is to use the [inAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin.

First, setup a simple server that accepts as GET parameter key-value parameters you want to persist.  I'm a python/tornado guy, so my server might look like:

```
class PersistCookieHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
      token = self.get_argument('token')
      self.set_secure_cookie('token',token)
```

Then, in your app:

```
function persistToken(token,success_cb, error_cb) {
    // replace with your URL
    url = 'SECURE_SERVER_URL_THAT_HANDLES_SET_COOKIE';  

    // _blank tells inAppBrowser to load in background (e.g., invisible)
    var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

    // attach a listener to the window which closes it when complete
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
        ref.close();
        success_cb();  // call our success callback
    });

    // attach a listener for server errors 
    ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { 
        // call our error callback
        error_cb(event);    
    });
}
```

You can then call this as follows:

```
persistToken(
   someToken,
   function() {
       console.log("token persisted");
   },
   function() {
       console.log("something went wrong);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `device_id` to address certain records on server side. Create a database table named `session` on your server with `device_id`, `cookiename`, `cookievalue` and `timestamp` as columns.

When a client accesses your web server via phonegap app, get his `device_id` and store the cookies in your table. The `device_id here` acts as the access token in OAuth protocol.

Now for security reasons you need to reduce the validity period of those records, because the device_id is permenant and your client would want to sell their phones one day. Therefore, use `timestamp` to store the last access by the client, and delete the record if it has not been accessed for, say 10 days.

Answer (score 3):

You can also append the session id to the requesting url and depending on the server application language, fetch session data using the query string session id value you passed - example in PHP you can open an existing session by passing in the session id. While this is not recommended due to risks of session hijacking you can easily test for the IP and Browser to make sure the session is coming from the same client. This would of course require you expire your session as soon as the client closes the session browser and would limit you from caching views since the session would be included in the actual html. Storing data on the local device for me at least is not really an option as it exposes too much to the client which is in my opinion a far greater security risk.

Comment: You can also send it through a post XmtHttpRequest, such as using `$.post()` in jQuery, then set a local variable. If you encrypt everything, that's pretty secure.

Comment: @JVE999 how to encrypt cookies which are saved  by default by web view?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Cordova 6.1 (newest version at the moment) and actually I found the following:

If I set the cookie via Javascript using document.cookie = ... then it does not work. However if I send a function setCookie via Ajax to the server with a function like

```
function setCookie(name, value, exdays) {

    if(isPhonegap() === true){
        var data = "typ=function&functionType=setCookie&name="+name+"&value="+value+"&exdays="+exdays;
        loadAjax(data, false);    
    }
    else if (!(document.cookie.indexOf("name") >= 0)){
            var expires;
            if (exdays) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
                expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else{
                expires = "";
            }
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"; 
    }
}
```

and set the cookie on the server side using

```
setcookie($cookie, $value, $expires , "/" );
```

then it does actually work!

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and decided to move evrth to localStorage
I wrote plugin so you can use it also: [angular-cookies-mirror](https://github.com/uamanager/angular-cookies-mirror)

Answer (score 0):

of course You can.

ionic app just send a ajax requset,cookie work good or not depend on server.

i have work with python Django server and node server,both cookie worked very well

node code below

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true);
next();
});
```

rest api

```
router.get('/setCookies', function(req, res, next) {
var now = new Date();
var nextYear=new Date(now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear()+1));
//you can change the cookie key and value by your self here
res.cookie('cookiesTest', 'set cookies success,your cookies can be set by server', { expires: nextYear, httpOnly: true });
res.status(200)
res.end('SET COOKIES SUCCESS')
});

router.get('/getCookies', function(req, res, next) {
res.status(200)
res.end(JSON.stringify(req.cookies))
});
```

ionic app code

```
var server='http://[YOUR IP HERE]:3000'

$scope.setCookies=function() {
  $http({
    url: server + '/setCookies',
    method: 'GET'
  }).success(function (data, header, config, status) {
    alert('set cookies success,look console')
    $scope.setCookiesStatu=false
    console.log(data)
    $scope.cookiesValue=data
  }).error(function (data, header, config, status) {
    alert('set cookies error,check console or your server address is wrong')
    console.log(data)
  });
}

$scope.getCookies=function() {
  $http({
    url: server + '/getCookies',
    method: 'GET'
  }).success(function (data, header, config, status) {
    alert('get cookies success,look console')
    console.log(data)
    $scope.cookiesValue=data
  }).error(function (data, header, config, status) {
    alert('get cookies error,check console or your server address is wrong')
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

[you can check my sourse code here](https://github.com/wangjinyang/ionic-angular-cookies/tree/master/nodeServer)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is fundamentally about setting client side cookies for a cordova app.  Most information on this topic implies that setting client side cookies does not work for cordova.

But I found a plugin that allows me to set client side cookies for my cordova app.

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cartegraph-cookie-master.

It just works!

Answer (score 0):

I also had session cookie issues with Cordova + XHR requests. The cookies are lost on every app restart. Two things have solved my issues:

1. Cookies must have an expiration date.
2. All XHR requests must have [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) flag set to true.