# Phonegap not propagating the session cookie

Tags: cookies, ios6, cordova

Using `Phonegap-3.0.0`+`ios6.1`, on a real iphone, on a real https domain handling the server side, many responses from different sources lead me to many trials and failures to deal with session cookies, I still cannot handle it correctly on an `Iphone5+Phonegap app`, although everything works perfectly in `Iphone5+Safari`.

**Sources of info & Understanding**

- [Cookies-in-PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova). This suggest to use another transport mechanism to exchange the cookie between clients and server. Deal with the cookies on the wire (javascript `set:document.cookie=...` and `get:xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')`) and keep it in Phonegap-html5-LocalStorage, to fetch it and reset it in the next ajax request.
- [Iphone & Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/ZJE1nxX63ow). I have located this cocoa code in the file `app>Classes>AppDelegate.m`.  I do not think I have to modify it.  It seems by default activated.  My php server still tell me `Your session has timed out, or you have disabled cookies.`.

I have been dealing with this client-server for months in different contexts, always worked, until phonegap came into the picture.

**Questions**

1. From the web readings, phonegap should already be set to go for cookie support.  Right or not ?
2. Does Phonegap really handle cookies by default (as is when creating a project) ?
3. Is cookie handling transport mechanism must be implemented by the developer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if cookies make sense here as in cordova our app is outside of the scope of domain you are talking to. Browser security does not let you set and receive cookies outside of your domain. If it is about storage better stick to html5 storage API (or better say enjoy it).