# GWT User Authentication like Spring Security?

Tags: authentication, gwt, grails, cordova, spring-security

I use [Google Webtoolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/) together with [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to build a mobile app. My app is communicating over a REST APi with my Backend Server.

What I want to do is a user authentication, i.e., my app user should be able to signup and login. If a user closes the app and reopens it, he should be authenticated again if he has not logged out before.

Usually, with Spring Security you do the authentication on the server by calling the required methods. The client (browser) then contains some cookie information for a persistent login.

**1. How can achieve this kind of authentication for my app?**

**2. Should I do the authentication as for a normal web site with the only difference that the authentication methods are called by the REST api methods?**

**3. Is there another way of doing the authentication for my mobile app?**

Answer (score 1):

I think user authentication for the mobile app will be the same as for a normal web-app.

The Spring backend will create a session once a user is authenticated. By default the user is authenticated for the duration of the specific session (until the user closes the browser/app).

Spring Security has a [Remember-me](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) functionality that is typically based on a `Cookie` approach and allows the user to be re-authenticated automatically..

I don't know if phonegap work with Cookies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova) for some pointers). I guess it depends on the plattform (if `webview` supports cookies).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you I wrote an article that show how to adapt Spring Security to secure REST services.

You can check it in here : http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/secure-rest-services-using-spring-security/

I also posted a working example which shows how I did use that with GWT on GitHub.