# Django 1.9 is not setting the sessionid cookie on login response only on Android with Cordova 6.0.0

Tags: android, django, cordova, session, cookies

Our Android users have started complaining that every time they kill our app, they have to log in again. I am able to reproduce this on our Android devices, but not our iOS devices, not through our mobile website on any device, and not through our desktop website.

When I attach the Chrome debugger to our Cordova app running on Android, it looks like Django is failing to set the sessionid cookie on the login response path. On every other platform (including straight Chrome on Android) when I look at the response for that endpoint, the sessionid cookie is there.

Here is what the normal login response looks like in every browser other than Cordova Android. Notice the setting of the sessionid cookie:

```
Response Headers
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:654
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Sat, 23 Apr 2016 22:33:44 GMT
    ETag:"11186a50be09093d01d4e82ff4d9d3e5;gzip"
    Server:nginx/1.8.1
    Set-Cookie:sessionid=25a9wodafd4zh8w0lzpklf8lnc7mxwbm; expires=Sat, 07-May-2016 22:33:44 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
    Vary:Cookie, Accept-Encoding
    X-Frame-Options:DENY
    X-Handled-By:127.0.0.1:8000
```

Here is the response I'm getting in Android through our Cordova app:

```
Response Headers
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:654
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Sat, 23 Apr 2016 22:52:23 GMT
    ETag:"11186a50be09093d01d4e82ff4d9d3e5;gzip"
    Server:nginx/1.8.1
    Vary:Cookie, Accept-Encoding
    X-Frame-Options:DENY
    X-Handled-By:127.0.0.1:8000
```

The request succeeds and the user somehow has a session and can make purchases. They can background the app and bring it up and their session is still there, but if they kill the app and bring it back up, they lose their session.

When I connect the Safari web debugger to our iOS Cordova app, the login response looks good. The sessionid cookie appears in the response header and everything works.

I'm hoping that there's something obvious about this whole process that I'm missing.

Comment: Looks like lots of other people are having the same issue - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471256/not-getting-cookies-in-android-phonegap-application) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318619/phonegap-cordova-set-and-get-cookies-for-login).

Comment: I am completely baffled. Persistent sessions have been working perfectly for hundreds of our users since January. These links indicate it should never have worked for anyone. Sounds like I will be implementing persistent session storage.