# Phonegap with persistent server session

Tags: angularjs, session, cordova, cookies

I'm developing a Phonegap application with a Spring back-end. Right now the phonegap part uses angular js to communicate with the Spring server. API calls work great--I can get and send information--but nothing will persist to the session while debugging in chrome.

I went through the debugger and noticed that there is no JSession id in the cookie store, which is normally there. The server is derived from similar servers I have used in the past and have never had problems with the session.

I'm using phonegap serve to render pages locally in chrome with the Ripple Emulator.

The good news is it seems to work fine on my Android device when I compile and run, but I need to be able to do client-side javascript debugging, which is currently not the case.

Any ideas on why my jSessionID cookie is missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova)

Comment: The difference between that question and this is in that one they want to store data clientside, whereas I just need an id.