# angular.js - set templateUrl dynamically by language (app.config stateprovider)

Tags: android, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile app using Ionic framework and I have a big problem to handle the multilanguage functionality for help page.

I have 2 languages (en + de) and I want to load help_en.html or help_de.html depending on the language.

I have set in the main controller the default language and the changeLanguage function which will set the lang in $cookies.language and it's working;

1.View:

```
    <a ng-href="#/help" >
```

2.MainCtrl -change language function:

```
    $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang) {
      $scope.translation=translationService.getTranslation($scope, lang);
      $cookies.lang=lang;
    };
```

3.The config from app.js looks something like that :

```
    var myApp = angular.module('MyPetApp', ['ionic', 'config', 'MyApp.controllers', 'ngCordova', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies']);

  myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    var $cookies;
    angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(function(_$cookies_) {
      $cookies = _$cookies_;
    });
    if ($cookies.language==undefined){
      $cookies.language = 'en'
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state('default', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "templates/default.html"
     })

    .state('help', {
        url: '/help', 
        templateUrl: function (){
            return 'templates/help_'+$cookies.lang+'.html'
        }
    })
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

This is working in chrome but on mobile will stay all the time on "en" language even I change the value from  $cookies.language to "de".

What can I do to get this job done? Any ideea ?
I really appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: any other simple and working method will be great

Comment: I think it's not a good solution  to create 2 states for aboutUs-en and de :)

Comment: Why are you using cookies and not local storage?

Comment: I'm using this example http://blog.novanet.no/creating-multilingual-support-using-angularjs/ ... I can change to localStorage if will work but just here (dynamic templateUrl ) I have this problem because on other pages cookies are working fine

Answer (score 1):

About you problems with cookies in a ionic & cordova app.. the solution is using **localStorage**. Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova)

About **i18n** I suggest you to use [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/). I have already used in a ionic app for android and ios. Is very useful if you need to translate all strings and small texts of you app.

Probably I had the same your problem in my help page, and because I had a lot of texts (some paragraphs) I prefered use plain html with all texts and showing only the current language with a simple ng-if:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list padding card" ng-if="settings.languageId == 'en'">
      ...
      English text here
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="list padding card" ng-if="settings.languageId == 'pt'">
      ...
      Portuguese text here
      ...
    </div>
</ion-content>
```