# How to show a cookie alert in phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cookies, google-analytics

I have a cordova app that has a cookie (from Google Analytics) and the users who install it in the EU region (e.g. Germany, London etc.) should receive a notification that a cookie is being used. 
I understand that a cookie can not be used in a Cordova app [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova). But the assumption in my app is that the GA cookie is dropped when the app opens a particular page (path of this page is fetched from my backend as a JSON).
How do we handle this scenario - to show an alert/notification in my app that a cookie is being used? Is this achievable at all? Please help.
[Example of a website where cookie usage notification is shown on the bottom of the page](http://www.bobmartin.co.uk/).

Comment: cookies should work on phonegap apps, but I don't think the cookies law applies to mobile apps, as far as I know it's only for websites

Comment: @jcesarmobile - true that mobile apps are not in cookie law purview, but mine is a Cordova app i.e. webview. What to do in this case?

Comment: An app is an app, a website is a website, if you create an app with cordova, it's an app, not a website