# Keep user sessions in Cordova Webview

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Assuming I have a e-commerce mobile site, where user can login, save some items in shopping cart, and checkout.

Can I point to this mobile site from my cordova app, and then expect the login/re-login will work? I.e. the user session and cookies will be kept correctly in Cordova Webviews?

p/s: I found an old question discussing this issue ([Handling cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova)), that was 4 years ago and I hope things are different now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "localStorage" to save session data

save:

```
 $window.localStorage['userinfo'] = JSON.stringify({
              username: user.username,
              password: user.password
            });
```

load:

```
  if ($window.localStorage['userinfo']) {
      var userinfo = $window.JSON.parse($window.localStorage['userinfo']);
      $scope.user.username = userinfo.username;
      $scope.user.password = userinfo.password;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm ....The tricky part is that I have no control over the e-commerce site. It is maintained by another team. I was hoping the login/session will work as it is...

Comment: In android, webview cookie will be saved at "data/data/package_name/app_WebView/Cookies.db". If you can save the cookies here, and after that, you load the webview, the cookie will be send properly. I don't try this by myself, hope this will help you.  you need write "native-code" to do this.  Some code snippets:`CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();`
 `cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie);`