# Session state not saved when accessed from Phonegap Application

Tags: cordova, iis, asmx, phonegap

Hello i have a phonegapp application that runs ajax call to a server that use IIS asmx application.

When i call ajax login from phonegap, it is successfully return logged in response but in Session in IIS application is not created.

I have read something about cookie based session but have not found any solutions.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually deal with the cookies required to maintain session state (see [Handling cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349237/handling-cookies-in-phonegap-cordova)), unless your IIS page is requiring [HTTP only cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie), which would require at least a plugin to send the correct headers as the browser won't let you set that value.

Comment: IIS page require cookies. So may you give me details of how to send it through phonegap? Thanks in advance