# UIWebView sends users back to login

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

I have an iPhone app that is a simple wrapper for a website. It worked fine pre-iOS5, but has problems with anything after that. It loads the website just fine, which begins with a simple login page. Once logged in, the user can navigate the pages okay. The problem, though, is that when the user attempts to send a message through the site (simple web form), it sends them back to the login page. When accessing the site through a desktop browser, or even through Safari on the iPhone, it works great and does not have this issue.

Here is the code:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest 
    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://xxxxxx"]]];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; ++x ){ 
    [[[[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:x]setHidden:YES];
}
```

Like I said, it's dead simple. It just doesn't behave the same as the Safari mobile browser. I suspect that it may have something to do with cookies, so I tried setting NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways, but that didn't have any effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: could it be due to javascript, turn off js in mobile safari and see if the form works

Comment: Have you implemented webview delegates??

Comment: turned off js in mobile safari and the form still works in the browser. Not sure if it matters, but the website uses JQueryMobile and probably hasn't been updated in a year.

Comment: Delegates might be the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626890/login-working-in-safari-but-not-in-uiwebview). I'll check it out.

Comment: After doing more research, it appears that JQuery Mobile has a lot of issues with UIWebView.